# Add Static Cell to Top of Dynamic TableView When Search Bar

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a dynamic tableview with a search bar.

How can I make a static cell (already added in storyboard) show up when the user types in the search bar?

current tableview:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
            return self.numSearchRows.count
        } else {
            return self.numRows.count
        }
    }
```

Like this:

[image: Example]

Comment: You can just adjust your filter function to append that row.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - for anyone else looking to do the same thing:

1. Create static cell and add it above your dynamic cells in storyboard
2. Add 1 row to your `numberOfRowsInSelection` (in my case for search results only)
3. Add your new static cell as the first row (adjust remaining rows to account for added row)

#### Code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
            return self.numberSearchRows.count + 1
        } else {
            return self.numberRows.count
        }
    }
```